# Links breaking in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, firefox

I have lately been finding that certain hyperlinks and submit buttons fail to work in Firefox, but never in Chrome.  These are links that worked before, then they fail, and later they may work again.  I never see this behavior in Chrome.

For example this bookmark link:

```
<div class="z_01">Paragraph text here.&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#ovr10" class="t_fq_links" style="text-decoration: none"><span class="blank"><img src="images\corner-right-up.svg" alt="Top"></span></a></div><br><br>
```

I have also had the same problem with form submit buttons that work not at all of just sporadically in Firefox.

On some links, the cursor will change to a hand on the left side of the link (or button) but not on the right side.

It’s not due to a Firefox add-on because I’m working in Firefox Developer Edition and I have no add-ons installed on that version.

I’m in Firefox Developer Edition 69, but the same problem occurs in Firefox 67 and 68.  It does not occur in Chrome 64.

Has anyone else seen this behavior in Firefox, and is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: Are there some JavaScripts on page. I had some troubles with Angular in some versions.

Comment: On some pages I have javascript and the problem has occurred, but on the page referenced above there is no javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is just the ID of another element on that same page. I'm assuming Chrome will be a little more smart than firefox and in the bookmarks change that link to https://www.whateverwebsite.com/whatever-page#ovr10 . I'm presuming Firefox only puts #ovr10 in your bookmarks. Only a guess though.

If that indeed is the problem and you want to fix this, changing your link to https://www.whateverwebsite.com/whatever-page#ovr10 would fix that particular issue.

**Edit:**
Tested on Firefox 65 (stable) and Firefox Dev 69.0b6. Link format does not appear to be the issue. Your code is also bookmarking fine for me.